# Swift 2 - Function not return Bool when using Alamofire

Tags: function, boolean, swift2, alamofire

I am creating a static function that checks if the user email for registration is in use. If the email is in use the function should return `true` otherwise `false`.

The code I have is returning always `false` and seems that the variable I use is not updated.

Any Idea what am I doing wrong and why is this not working as expected?

```
    class userInfo: NSObject {

    static func userRegistration(email: String) -> Bool {

           var emailIsavailable = false

            Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example/check_email.php?email=\(email)")


                .responseString{ response in


                    if let responseValue = response.result.value {

                        print("Response String: \(responseValue)")

                        if responseValue == "email is available"{


                            print("email available")

                            emailIsavailable = true //emailIsavailable is not updated

                        }else{


                            print("email not available")

                           emailIsavailable = false //emailIsavailable is not updated


                        }

                    }
            }



            return emailIsavailable // returns always false
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it run in different thread so you can't return straight. You should use callback (or another call block, closure). You should edit code:

```
   class userInfo: NSObject {

static func userRegistration(email: String, callBack : (emailIsavailable : Bool) -> Void) {



        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example/check_email.php?email=\(email)")


            .responseString{ response in


                if let responseValue = response.result.value {

                    print("Response String: \(responseValue)")

                    if responseValue == "email is available"{


                        print("email available")

                        callBack(emailIsavailable: true)

                    }else{


                        print("email not available")

                      callBack(emailIsavailable: false)


                    }

                }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can call like:

```
yourInstance.userRegistration("test") { (emailIsavailable) -> Void in
        //you can get emailIsavaiable or something here
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a very valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

That function will always return `false` because the networking request started is **asynchronous** (and it's the response from that request that can change the value of `emailIsavailable`).

Being **asynchronous** basically means that the response won't be received synchronously with the execution of that function.

I would suggest changing that function signature by removing the return type, `-> Bool`, and add a completion handler as a parameter. Then you'd call that handler when the response is received.

Something along the lines of:

```
class userInfo: NSObject {

    static func userRegistration(email: String, completionHandler: ((String) -> Void)) {

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example/check_email.php?email=\(email)")
            .responseString{ response in

                if let responseValue = response.result.value {
                    completionHandler(responseValue)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

func foo() -> Bool {
    var ret = false
    // asynchronous code

    // asyn will return immediately !!!
    async { () -> () in
        ret = true
        print("print ret from completion block:", ret)
    }
    // ret value is false at this point
    return ret
}

// this function is executed on its own queue. (aka Alamofire do)
func async(completion: ()->()) {
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("async", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
    dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in
        // do something and then
        // execute completion
        completion()
    }
}

// will always return false !!
print("foo return:", foo())


/*
foo return: false
print ret from completion block: true
*/
```

You have to design your own synchronisation mechanism. Generally if you need a result of some function execution, that function must be executed synchronously.